# Setting table body to hidden before using JavaScript to click on the table head to view the body

Tags: javascript, css, hidden

I have multiple tables on my page taking up space so want to set a toggle on the table headers to be able to hide/show the table body when clicked. I've got this working below.

Have created tables..e.g. LicenceTable1…

```
table.LicenceTable1 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-width: 0.5px;
  border-color: #008842;
  border-style: solid;
  color: #000000;
}

table.LicenceTable1 td, table.LicenceTable1 th {
  border-width: 0.5px;
  border-color: #008842;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 3px;
}

table.LicenceTable1 thead {
  background-color: #008842;
}
```

Then have some JavaScript to display/hide the body of the table when you click on the table heading
JS:

```
$(function() {    
$(".LicenceTable1 > thead > tr").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".LicenceTable1").find("tbody > tr").slideToggle();
});
});
```

But when I land on the page the body of the table is visible. Is there a quick way to make the body of the table hidden **until** you click on the Heading?

Comment: Did you add `display: none;` to your `tbody styling`

Comment: With that though I cannot display the body when clicking on the heading. It just hides the body completely.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a helper class and set is as default for table bodies. For example:

```
table tbody.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

In your HTML, add this class to the bodies.

```
<tbody class="someclass hidden">
  ...
</tbody>
```

When click the table heading, just toggle the `hidden` class.

```
function toggleTableBody (header) {
  const body = header.parentNode.querySelector('tbody');
  body.classList.toggle('hidden');
}
```

Comment: Would this change the class of all my tables??
Sorry......I'm still a novice when it comes to development :-(

Comment: I have other tables on the page that are not data-tables so don't want to hide anything on them.

Comment: You only need to add the `hidden` class to any table body that you want. If you do not want that X table can hide it's body, simply do not add this class. Remember, you can have many classes for an element (`<tbody className="class1 class2 class3">`).